# Azure: Flexible schemas using TableStorage

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, azure, dynamic-schema

I need to make an asp.net MVC 2 c# webapp where each tenant could define some special fields to a class. So for example, in the same app some users will have the field "age", other users will have other field and not necessarily "age". Which is the best way to do this? There is any blog/tutorial/book with an example of this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As I commented in your other similar question, you can use List or Array objects to store dynamic properties.  They are serializable and will persist to TableStorage.

Answer (score 0):

See http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsazure/thread/f57cb566-cc7a-4b31-b1ab-47b6d16604af/